# Freeswitch ESL library

Tags: freeswitch

I would like understand the data format of Freeswitch ESL library method getBody and also from the ESl how to get the media bugs list on channel issuing the command api uuid_buglist .

My concern is that I can issue the command but how to read the data that comes out is my problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

esl_event_get_body() is a very simple wrapper function that returns `event->body` from an **event**.
To get the reply from your cmd you should use `handle.last_sr_event->body` after using `esl_send_recv(&handle, cmd)`

Answer (score 0):

you can see my open source project, it is a auto dial project:

https://github.com/nwaycn/nway_ac

here is plain the message of hangup

```
con = ESLconnection(fs_ip, fs_esl_port, fs_esl_auth)
    if con.connected():
        thread.start_new_thread(AutoCall,(1,1))
        e = con.events('plain','CHANNEL_HANGUP_COMPLETE')
        while True:
            ee = con.recvEvent()
            #print ee
            if ee:
                my_number =  ee.getHeader('Caller-Caller-ID-Number')
                dest_number = ee.getHeader('Caller-Destination-Number')
                SetNumberIdle(dest_number)

    con.disconnect();
```

here is to call a phone

```
def CallOut(dial_string,call_number):
    con = ESLconnection(fs_ip, fs_esl_port, fs_esl_auth)
    if con.connected():
        e = con.api(dial_string)
        SetNumberBusy(call_number)
        print e.getBody()
    else:
        print 'not Connected'
    con.disconnect();
```